# How to order by maximum of two column which can be null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

```
create table jobs(
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        .....
        salaryminus INTEGER UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
        salaryplus INTEGER UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
        .....
);
```

I want to do something like :

```
Select * from jobs order by maxof(salaryminus, salaryplus) limit 10;
```

`maxof(Null,1000)` should be 1000,

How to implement the `maxof`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know that `salaryplus` will always be greater than `salaryminus`, then you can do

```
order by coalesce(salaryplus, salaryminus, 0)
```

`coalesce` will return the first value which is not null, or (in this example) 0, if both values are null.

Otherwise, do something like this:

```
order by greatest(ifnull(salaryminus,0), ifnull(salaryplus,0))
```

This will treat both `salaryminus` and `salaryplus` as 0 if they are null, and will order by the larger of the two.

Comment: Note that `GREATEST` is not standard SQL.

Comment: It is not in the standard, but is provided by MySQL, as well as PostgreSQL, and Oracle. It's spelled "`MAX`" in SQLite. If you have to use SQL Server, or need to write standard SQL for a homework question, use "`ORDER BY CASE WHERE salaryminus > salaryplus THEN salaryminus ELSE salaryplus END`"

Answer (score 1):

Just found another way to solve this.

And will be supported by other SQLs as well:

```sql
SELECT * FROM jobs 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN salaryminus > salaryplus THEN salaryminus
    ELSE salaryplus
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to turn possibly-null columns into specific values instead -- e.g., `coalesce(salaryminus, -99999999)` will give a large negative number if salaryminus is null, but will return salaryminus if not null.