# How to order by max of multiple fields in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table where each record contains 3 fields which are dates (some of which may be null), among other data. I'd like to be able to order my results by the max date found in any of the 3 date fields in descending order. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611490/how-to-order-by-maximum-of-two-column-which-can-be-null-in-mysql) answer for MySQL, which is exactly what I want to do, but it seems like the functions mentioned there do not exist in Access.

Using American date formatting, if my data is

```
id    date1       date2       date3
------------------------------------
 1   1/1/2001   1/2/2001     10/3/2001
 2   7/1/2001   1/2/2002     1/8/2001
 3   1/18/2001  6/2/2001     1/3/2003
 4   12/1/2001  5/4/2001     8/9/2001
```

I'd like to return

```
id    date1       date2       date3
------------------------------------
 3   1/18/2001  6/2/2001     1/3/2003
 2   7/1/2001   1/2/2002     1/8/2001
 4   12/1/2001  5/4/2001     8/9/2001
 1   1/1/2001   1/2/2001     10/3/2001
```

How do I create my ORDER BY clause to get this order the way I'd like?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MS Access does not offer `least()` or `greatest()`.  You can do this in a brute force way:

```
order by iif(date1 > date2 and date1 > date3, date1,
             iif(date2 > date3, date2, date3)
            )
```

Comment: Didn't you mean: `order by iif(date1 > date2 and date1 > date3, date1, iif(date2 > date3, date2, date3)`

Comment: @Gustav . . . Yes, that is definitely what I meant.